# jquery isolate functions according with table's id

Tags: jquery, function

I have two tables:

- table 1:  id=cotizar  (sum all input fields, not must include any field of the second table)
- table 2:  id=comision (calculate a commision value)

But the first one propagate its calculateSum function when I use the second one.

How can I isolate correctly them?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/200313/nmsrohnm/

HTML:

```html
<table id=cotiza border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#E8DCFF">

                <tr>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>Materiales</td>
                   <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Servicios</td>
                    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                       <td>&nbsp;</td>
                       <td align="right">Total</td>
                       <td align="center"><span id="ssum">0</span></td>
                 </tr>
 </table>



<br>

 <table id=comision border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#E8DCFF">
          <tr>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>Total Facturado</td>
               <td><input id=fact type="text" name="txt"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                 <td>2</td>
                 <td align="right">Comision a Pagar </td>
                 <td align="center"><span id="Ccomision">0</span></td>
           </tr>
</table>
```

SCRIPT:

```js
$("table#comision").each(function(){
    $(this).keyup(function(){
       calctotal = $('#fact').val() * 0.10 ; 
       console.log('CALC ->' + $('#fact').val() );

       $("#Ccomision").html(calctotal.toFixed(2));
    });

});

$("table#cotizar").ready(function(){
         $(":text").each(function(){$(this).keyup(

                        function(){calculateSum();});});});

                        function calculateSum(){
                        var sum=0;
                        $(":text").each(
                        function(){if(!isNaN(this.value)&&this.value.length!=0){
                                sum+= parseFloat(this.value);
                                subtotal =  sum ;
                        }});

                        $("#ssum").html(subtotal.toFixed(2) );

}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "how can I isolate correctly them?"

Comment: What do you think `$("table#cotizar").ready(...)` does? And why are you using `.each()` on `$("table#comision")`?

Comment: @nnnnn, table-cotizar must show only the sumatory of the  values entered in input fields of that table, but currently also it is showing result when I put a value in the table-comision's field.

What dou you recommend? how could I fix that?

Comment: @mina-jacob, I mean when I put some value in the table-comision, the value is also added in table-cotizar, showing result on table-cotizar that we don't want to see (we want see only when we use it).

Comment: Hi @nnnnnn, guys, any comment? 

I've put a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/200313/nmsrohnm/

thanks

Answer (score 0):

after some attempts I had to use a class instead a :text selector, so the script that has worked has a little change in this part:

```js
$("table#cotizar").ready(function(){
         $("table#cotizar").each(function(){$(this).keyup(

                        function(){calculateSum();});});});

                        function calculateSum(){
                        var sum=0;
                        $(".txt").each(
                        function(){if(!isNaN(this.value)&&this.value.length!=0){
                                sum+= parseFloat(this.value);
                                subtotal =  sum ;
                        }});

                        $("#ssum").html(subtotal.toFixed(2) );

}
```

Bye.